# Equation of a plane in vector form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a basic doubt. If we are given 3 points in space then the equation of the plane passing through them is given by:

$$ \Bigg[\vec{r} - \vec{a}, \vec{a} - \vec{b}, \vec{a} - \vec{c}\Bigg] = 0$$

where $ \vec{r} $ is the position vector of the variable point and $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ are the fixed points. This equation is true because the box product of coplanar vectors is $0$. However, if we see then even this:

$$ \Bigg[\vec{r} - \vec{a}, \vec{r} - \vec{b}, \vec{r} - \vec{c}\Bigg] = 0$$

satisfies the condition - the box product of 3 coplanar vectors is zero. However, if we right this is Cartesian form, then we don't get a linear equation and that wouldn't represent a plane, would it?

Comment: What is a box product?

Comment: The box product of 3 vectors $ \vec {a}, \vec {b}, \vec {c}$ is $[\vec {a}, \vec {b}, \vec {c}] = \vec {a} \times \vec {b} \cdot \vec {c}$. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_triple_product#Scalar_triple_product). You could've as well googled it up!

Comment: Sorry, but I kept getting links to stuff about boxes of products for sale. (I usually use Yahoo by the way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented earlier, box product is rusty for me, but looks to me that the expressions are the same.

$$\Big[\vec{r} - \vec{a}, \vec{r} - \vec{b}, \vec{r} - \vec{c}\Big] = 0$$

is equivalent to 
$$(\vec{r} - \vec{a}) \times (\vec{r} - \vec{b})\cdot(\vec{r} - \vec{c}) = 0$$

$$(\vec{r}\times \vec{r} - \vec{r} \times \vec{b} - \vec{a}\times\vec{r} +\vec{a}\times\vec{b} )\cdot(\vec{r} - \vec{c}) = 0$$

$$(- \vec{r} \times \vec{b} - \vec{a}\times\vec{r} +\vec{a}\times\vec{b} )\cdot(\vec{r} - \vec{c}) = 0$$

Noting $\vec{r} \times \vec{r}= 0$ and expanding, 
$$[\vec{r}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}]+[\vec{a}, \vec{r}, \vec{c}]+[\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{r}]-[\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}] = 0$$

So this should not lead to a non-linear equation!  Further, 
I leave testing if the first expression expands to the same to you...

Comment: Wow! I thought I was wrong. Your argument seems more convincing and  rigorous :D

Comment: I forget all operations for box product, but IIRC cyclic shifting of elements leave them unchanged and flipping two will introduce a negative sign.  Essentially $[\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}] = \det[\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}]$  So by row reduction you should be able to show the two expressions are really the same.

Comment: I see, I should have done the computation explicitly :-) The non linear terms vanish as $(r\times b)\cdot r= (r\times r)\cdot b$ and similarly for $(r\times a)\cdot r$. One little thing: I believe it is $+a\times b$ in the expansion of the box equation.

Comment: @Avitus - Thanks. will correct that sign error.

Comment: Now I feel I should've done too!

Comment: @Macavity - thank you for the clarifying computations

Answer (score 1):

A plane in $\mathbb R^3$ is a codimension $1$-linear subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, whose general form in cartesian coordinates is given by

$$ax+by+cz+d=0,$$

with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$. The second box-plot equation you wrote is not linear in the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ of $r$, so it does not represent a plane.

**EDIT**: The above statement in the case of the box equation is not true, as the quadratic terms in the components of $r$ vanish, as shown in Macavity's answer.

The following *caveat* remains valid.

In general, note that the points

$$a=(1,0,0),$$
$$b=(0,1,0),$$
$$c=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0)$$

are co-planar and satisfy the equation

$$x^2+y^2-1=0;$$

this latter does not describe a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, however. In other words, given an equation in the  coordinates $(x,y,z)$ which is satisfied by co-planar triples $a,b,c$ does not imply that the given equation describes a plane in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Are you sure of this?  My box-product is rusty, but if I recall right, it should be a determinant in which you should NOT get a non-linear form even in the second case (by row or column reduction).  Geometrically it is the volume of a parallelopiped, so I think the second form also expresses this correct.

Comment: Uhm...I am not sure 'bout that: it seems to me that you need extra conditions on $a,b,c$. Take, for example $a=(0,0,0)$, $b=(1,0,0)$ and $c=(0,0,1)$ (a non planar triple). The second box equation, which is a determinant as you correctly pointed out, gives $r=0$, which is no plane. A sufficient condition for the second box equation to give a plane is $c$  parallel to $a-b$. In that case it reduces to $(a\times b )\cdot (r-c)=0$.

Comment: No. That gives the plane $y=0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the volume of the tetrahedron with vertices $\vec{r}$, $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$. This tetrahedron has 6 sides, namely the vectors $\vec{r} - \vec{a}$, $\vec{r} - \vec{b}$, $\vec{r} - \vec{c}$, $\vec{b} - \vec{a}$, $\vec{c} - \vec{a}$, $\vec{b} - \vec{c}$. The "box product" of **any** three of these 6 vectors gives $6V$ (which is actually the volume of a parallelipiped). You get the same result no matter which three of the six you use.

So, in particular, using the two box products you mentioned, we have
$$
\Big[\vec{r} - \vec{a}, \vec{r} - \vec{b}, \vec{r} - \vec{c}\Big] = 
\Big[\vec{r} - \vec{a}, \vec{a} - \vec{b}, \vec{a} - \vec{c}\Big]
$$

Macavity's answer shows algebraically that this is true. My only point is that it is (fairly) obvious geometrically, too, if you understand how box products relate to volumes.